# Using star projection as a supertype in Kotlin

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

Can anyone help me explain what's going on here?

```
private val map1 = mutableMapOf<String, Data<State<*>>>()
private val map2 = mutableMapOf<String, Data<*>>()

init {
    map1.put("1", Data<State<String>>()) //it does not work
    map2.put("2", Data<State<String>>()) //it works
    map2.put("3", Data<State<Int>>()) //it works
}

class Data<T>
class State<T>
```

I read from Kotlin docs that if the type is unknown, you can use star projection(*) and then later use any type. So why doesn't it work for the first case? It says `Type Mismatch Error`.

Comment: This might be a dumb idea but trying changing the T in state to a different letter

Comment: I set mutableMapOf<String, Data<State<*>>>() to mutableMapOf<String, Data<out State<*>>>() and it worked. I don't know why. @NickMowen

Comment: Note: I edited my answer to clarify how `Data<out State<*>>` relates to existential types. Making a comment so you can see it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Data<*>` is the common supertype of `Data<String>`, `Data<Any>`, `Data<AnythingYouPutThere>`. But `Data<State<*>>` is *not* a common supertype of `Data<State<String>>` etc.; it's `Data` with a specific type parameter `State<*>` (which is the supertype of `State<String>` etc.)

Unfortunately, Kotlin doesn't support general existential types as Scala does, but in those terms `Data<State<*>>` is `Data<State<T> forSome T>` while you want `Data<State<T>> forSome T`.

> I set `mutableMapOf<String, Data<State<*>>>()` to `mutableMapOf<String, Data<out State<*>>>()` and it worked. I don't know why

`Data<out State<*>>` allows any subtype of `State<*>` as type parameter of `Data`. So it can also be expressed as an existential type: `Data<T> forSome T : State<*>`, which isn't *quite* `Data<State<T>> forSome T`, because `State<*>` can have subtypes which aren't `State<Something>`. For example, if you have `class State2 extends State<Int>()`, `Data<out State<*>>` allows `Data<State2>`, but `Data<State<T>> forSome T` wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the docs here on [projection and declaration variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance)

It says that out is required to tell the compiler the type of the <>

Answer (score 1):

According to docs, say you have a class

```
class Source<X>
```

you can not do this

```
val source: Source<Any> = Source<String>()
```

even though String inherits from Any. This is called invariance. To support this functionality you will have to use Kotlin's Declaration-site variance. You just need to add **out** modifier to the type parameter X.

```
class Source<out X>
```

The catch to this is that you can not consume X in any of the methods of Source class, for e.g.

```
class Source<out X> {
    fun modifyX(x: X) {} //not allowed
}
```

You can only produce X i.e. set the return type of methods to X